# Which Buffalo Way is stronger?

Tags: inequality, buffalo-way

Let $f(x, y, z)$ be a homogeneous polynomial and we want to prove $_{cyc}\Sigma f\ge0$. There are two different strat with the same name Buffalo Way for this problem.

1. Let $\min(x, y, z)=x$, expand $_{cyc}\Sigma f(x, x+u, x+v)$ and prove.
2. Assume $x\le y\le z$, expand $_{cyc}\Sigma f(x, x+u, x+u+v)$ and prove. Assume $x\ge y\ge z$ and repeat.

**Question.**

Which of these strat is stronger?

- If one of the strat is stronger: Is there a proof?
- If none of the strat is stronger than the other: Is there polynomials $f_1$ and $f_2$ whose positivity can only be proved using strat 1 and 2 respectively?

Comment: They are both useful and fun to use. I don't think one can say 1. is better than 2. or vice versa. It all depends on the problem at hand. But it seems to me that the methods are equivalent, meaning that if one can prove the problem with 1. then one can also prove the same problem with 2. and vice versa.

Comment: Consider the problems with non-negative variables $x, y, z \ge 0$. If BW 1 gives a polynomial with non-negative coefficients, then BW 2 also gives a polynomial with non-negative coefficients. Sometimes, BW 1 does not give a polynomial with non-negative coefficients (BW 1 can still work by further steps), but BW 2 can give a polynomial with non-negative coefficients.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example that shows to you Buffalo way can't kill cyclic inequalities all
$$\left ( y- z \right )^{2}\left ( y+ z \right )^{2}x^{5}+ 2\left ( y+ z \right )\left ( y^{4}+ z^{4} \right )x^{4}+ \left ( 8y^{3}z^{3}- y^{4}z^{2}+ z^{6}+ y^{6}- y^{2}z^{4} \right )x^{3}-$$
$$- 2yz\left ( y^{2}+ z^{2} \right )\left ( y+ z \right )^{3}x^{2}+ y^{2}z^{2}\left ( y^{4}+ 6y^{2}z^{2}+ z^{4} \right )x+ 4y^{4}z^{4}\left ( y+ z \right )\geq 0$$
holds true for $x, y, z> 0$.
Author: Art of Problem Solving/@xzlbq ([Liu Bao Qian](https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c6h2347131p18982031))

Yes, your strategy is up to the form of acceptance. For the given example, you should follow the second strategy. Actually there is no need.